# how to find the name or path of the image saved in gallery of iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ios4

In my application i have to upload images saved in my gallery of iphone to server using php.

I am able to uplaod image on server along with date and time when it is upload, but i want to upload the image with its name on server.
please help me out.

following in my code:

```
-(IBAction)upload:(id)sender
{

NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]; [format setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMddHHmmss"];

    NSDate *now = [[NSDate alloc] init];

    NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Image_%@", [format stringFromDate:now]];

    [now release];
    [format release];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://url"]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    /*
     Set Header and content type of your request.
     */
    NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"---------------------------Boundary Line---------------------------"];
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

    /*
     now lets create the body of the request.
     */
    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];    
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"%@.jpg\"\r\n", imageName] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageView.image, 90)]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    //[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"geotag=%@&", [self _currentLocationMetadata]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    // set body with request.
    [request setHTTPBody:body];
    [request addValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [body length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

    // now lets make the connection to the web
    [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    //


}
```

Comment: are you getting the image from photo library ?

Comment: yes harish sir ..i am able to browse image from photo library and i am able to upload image as well....but i want to upload image with its name.......

Comment: harish sir ....and how to upload mutiple images from iphone to server

Answer (score 0):

In the UIImagePickerControllerDelegate method

```
    - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
   NSString *tempFilePath = [[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] path];
}
```